# How to find all possible correlations between n vectors

Tags: list-manipulation, probability-or-statistics

Given the Matrix

```
M = {{31.3, 31.2, 29.7, 29.7, 29.8, 29.2, 28.7, 28.3, 28.2, 28.2},
   {31.7, 30.7, 30.7, 30.1, 30.2, 29.8, 29.2, 28.7, 28.5, 27.7},
   {24.0, 24.2, 23.7, 23.7, 23.2, 23.1, 22.6, 22.2, 22.1, 21.7},
   {23.2, 22.2, 22.2, 22.0, 22.2, 21.8, 19.5, 19.1, 19.1, 18.9}};
```

I want to get a list of all possible correlations between its vectors.

With

```
x1 = Take[#, 2] & /@ Permutations[Range@Length@M];
```

And

```
x2 = Union@Cases[x1, {a_, b_} /; a < b];
```

I get the necessary permutation:

```
{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}}
```

Finally, with

```
Correlation @@@ Partition[M[[Flatten@x2]], 2]
```

I get the desired result:

```
{0.923, 0.933, 0.893, 0.952, 0.946, 0.934}
```

I am, of course, not happy with this code and would wellcome any suggestion how one could write this succinctly.

Comment: Are you looking for `Subsets[..., {2}]`?

Comment: @Szabolcs - Thanks, "Cases[Subsets[Range@Length@M, 2], {_, _}]" is very nice ! But I also think that the following "Partition[M[[Flatten@x2]], 2]" is not the most efficient way.

Comment: `Correlation @@@ Subsets[M, {2}]`?

Comment: @kguler - you make me speechles. Why didn't you post this as the one and only answer? You don't want me to earn two pennies by accepting it?

Comment: @eldo, you got your two 'pennies' :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Correlation @@@ Subsets[M, {2}]
(* {0.923, 0.933, 0.893, 0.952, 0.946, 0.934}  *)
```